# A Vagrant environment or target machine is required

Tags: laravel, vagrant, vagrantfile, homestead

I am trying to set up homestead. I have tried to add new custom domain but I forgot that I have to run the command vagrant provision and I got an error, so I have decided to uninstall Vagrant VirtualBox and start from scratch but I have realy messed the things up.

Now I have installed VirtualBox, Vagrant. I have cloned the repository of homestead on my home directory. I filled the Homestead.yaml but when I start with vagrant up I get this error

A Vagrant environment or target machine is required to run this
command. Run `vagrant init` to create a new Vagrant environment. Or,
get an ID of a target machine from `vagrant global-status` to run
this command on. A final option is to change to a directory with a
Vagrantfile and to try again.
Also I have tried to require homestead through composer but I`am still getting the same error.

When I try with vagrant init a new box is created and when I start vagrant up I am not in the homestead box but in the one that I last created.

I am really confused and I don`t know what I am missing. Any help will be appreciated.

edit.

Also when I try with homestead up, the virtual machine is running and I am able to connect through ssh but when I type custom domains I get "No input file specified."

update:

In the ~/.homestead directory I have executed `vagrant init laravel/homestead` and now I can start the the machine and to connect through ssh but I can`t go to a registered custom domain - the page is not available.

Update 2:

Also I just checked and on the homestead server my Code folder is empty. In the `Homestead.yaml`file I have folders 
`- map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code`

All my projects are there in the local folder and I have no idea why they are not on vagrant.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

99% you're in wrong directory. Make sure that the directory includes **Vagrantfile**.

Comment: Maybe you are in the wrong branch, too! :) I was my case

Comment: DAMN! Happened with me, and I wandered for about 30 mins.
Was about to delete the VMs itself.

Comment: @RavishRawat I also took me quite long time to figure that one out :)

Answer (score 7):

Can you run `vagrant global-status` to see if there is already a Vagrant server running?  Then you can use `vagrant up [server-id]` to get into the existing one.

Comment: I have tried this but again I go the error for missing Vagrantfile

Answer (score 2):

As someone said earlier, you could be in the wrong directory. Actually going to the right directory containing the 'Vagrantfile' was all that solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Before trying anything else make sure you are in the correct directory. I mean, vagrantfile must be present in the directory. I was able to fix it by

1. One vagrant server was already running in my case. vagrant global-status helped me to see it.
2. Then I used vagrant up [server-id] to get into the existing one.

Comment: I tried with everything and at the end I found out I was not in a proper directory.

Answer (score 1):

> Also when I try with homestead up, the virtual machine is running and
>   I am able to connect through ssh but when I type custom domains I get
>   "No input file specified."

Did you add your custom domains to your `Homestead.yaml` file in the sites section and run `vagrant provision

Comment: Yes, this was the reason for this but when I have added them I got 502 bad gateway

Comment: hum .. what the log says ?

Comment: when I run `vagrant provision` nothing happens I am not sure if there should be any answer in the terminal.

Comment: Where I can check out the log?

Comment: The file is empty. I am not sure if the registered custom domain refers to the server. But I have registered the domain in `/etc/hosts` file and in the `Homestead.yaml`